# How the quasar framework uses less?

Tags: command-line-interface, quasar

```
/** Options to supply to `less-loader`. */
  lessLoaderOptions: object;
```

Create projects by default with sass, scss, css, no less.

Comment: do you have some more details?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YkCx.png)

Inside the quasar creation framework,There are sass, scss, styles and css. But There's no less here.At https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js-Property%3A-build, I found LoaderOptions but didn't know if the framework had a built-inless loader and how to use it.